# Paypal response not coming on the notify_url page in Paypal IPN

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to test my paypal application and specified my paypal notify_url as www.xx.com/paypal.aspx. I should be getting response from the sandbox paypal. But I am not getting anything on the paypal.aspx page. My repsonse processing code is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnStr"].ConnectionString;
        con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        con.Open();
        //Post back to either sandbox or live
        string strSandbox = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        // string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strSandbox);

        //Set values for the request back
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
        string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
        strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;


StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    streamOut.Write(strRequest);
    streamOut.Close();
    StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
    streamIn.Close();

    if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
    {
       //Insert statement
    }


else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
    {
        //UPDATE YOUR DATABASE

        StreamWriter swr = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("Textfile.txt"));
        swr.WriteLine("---- not verified(" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ")--");
        swr.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {  //UPDATE YOUR DATABASE

        //TextWriter txWriter = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("../uploads/") + Session["orderID"].ToString() + ".txt");
        //txWriter.WriteLine("Invalid");
        ////log response/ipn data for manual investigation
        //txWriter.Close();
    }
```

The payment is processed fully. I am also directed to the thank you page. Please HELP

Thanks

Comment: First of all the open of the database and you forget to use it and close it. Why you have it here anyway ?. Second what is actually the problem on this code ? since you say that is not called at all the issue is on what url you send to paypal. From where do you expect this to be called ? from your local computer behind asdn rooter, from the server on a static ip ? from where ?

Comment: I have opened the database connection. The code is not the problem,this is the page where I should be getting the IPN response. But I just checked the IPN history and the status is FAILED there, though my transactions are happening. I am sorry for the poor framing of question. It is to be called from server.

Comment: you open the database in wrong way, and you forget to close it - bad code on that. Now, is this page called or not ?

Comment: I am a begginer can you please tell me how can i improve my code in opening the database. Yes I have specified this page in the IPN notification url .

Comment: open and close the database only the moment you goint to use it, if you going to use it, and use the "using(con = new SqlConnection(connStr)){ }"  see the example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx

Comment: Now, my question is "Is this page actually called ?" do you know if this is called ? can you place some debug log to check that this is called ?

Comment: Thanks I will make the changes in the code. What should I be doing for the FAILED status in the IPNN history?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9532/discussion-between-aristos-and-vini)

Comment: Have you logged in to Sandbox just before running your app? Also, do not use a ReturnURL from PayPal...

Comment: Yes even if i log in before it still asks for login and is the return url an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to make sure that the URL you are passing to PayPal as the notify_url value is a publicly valid and resolvable URL. Meaning, make sure you are not sending it an internal network URL or machine name (i.e.  localhost,  my_computer_name, mypcname.mynetwork.com ). Easy way to check that and make sure you haven't created a bad name or have an incorrect network configuration, is take whatever URL you are sending to PayPal as the notify_url value, and have a friend that is external to your network try to access the URL in their browser. If they get a connection error, you have to rethink your network configuration or naming before you can get PayPal to see your machine.

Second, if you are running the above code in Visual Studio using the debugger and build in web server, you might be limited to it only responding to requests if the requested site name is "localhost". See the following Microsoft article on how to setup your code to run in an actual instance of IIS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx